# Make 'each' a synonym for 'foreach'

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Looking at info for [each](/questions/tagged/each), it appears the tag should just be made a synonym of [foreach](/questions/tagged/foreach).

Comment: It's not exactly the same as a `foreach`, it appears to be a specific jQuery construct. It doesn't have my vote.

Comment: This was based on reading the tag excerpt, so maybe that needs updating.

Comment: Also, there appear to only be 36 questions tagged [tag:for-loop] and [tag:each] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/for-loop+each). That implies that it may have a different usage.

Comment: I'd rather we get rid of both tags.  There's no real use for them.

Comment: @casperOne maybe [tag:each], but [tag:foreach]?

Comment: Yep.  I mean, are you *really* interested in `foreach` across the bazillion programming languages it's in?  It's worthless in how generic it is, just like `string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

`each` and `foreach` mean two different things.

**[`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach)** can be implied to be used for the PHP **[`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach)** loop.
**[`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)** is a method in the jQuery library.

Comment: You should totally drop that and use jQue.... oh, wait.